# Security - Do mobile devices (Android & iOS) Block/Drop ICMP ECHO requests?

Tags: android, iphone, security, mobile

Upon doing some sniffing on my home network using programs like Ettercap and Wireshark. I issued a Broadcast ping at .255 to ensure my ARP Table was populated. Every other device on my network responded with an ICMP packet, besides my Android and iOS devices. I took it further by MITM ARP attacking my Android device and it worked fine. The MITM was successful and all traffic was routed through my laptop, however i'm curious as to why my ICMP packets didn't cause my mobile devices to respond. My guess is that they just block, but i'm wondering if anybody knows exact reasoning.

Comment: Even if mobile devices don't, most networks do.  Any cellular network will.  I would expect most phones will, because the number of security issues they can cause dwarfs the number of uses they have in the hands of the average consumer.  Of course Android is linux underneath, so you can always override this behavior from a shell if you root the device.

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not block ICMP ECHO requests, at least not in the general case when the phone is active. I've pinged iOS many times in the past, but to double check I just pinged an iPhone running iOS 12 on my home network and it responded both to direct pings and a broadcast ping to .255. It did not respond to pings while asleep.